# Haskell tool to rewrite import statements to name all imports?

Tags: haskell, import

While writing Haskell code, I often simply type

```
import System.Environment
import System.Directory
```

Is there a tool available that will amend these import statements and add the function names I actually use back into the import statements? Such as:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.Directory (getDirectoryContents)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use ghc's `-ddump-minimal-imports` flag. For an example, see [Cleaning up your Haskell imports](http://gbacon.blogspot.com/2009/06/cleaning-up-your-haskell-imports.html) on my blog.